# HTTP Streaming from VLC freezes after 15 seconds

Tags: video, video-streaming, vlc

I'm trying to use VLC to create a live http stream from a ubuntu desktop to an html5 video tag.

Here's the command I use to create the stream:

```
me@kaffeesatz:~$ vlc screen:// --screen-left=67 --screen-top=53 --screen-width=800 --screen-height=600 --screen-fps=15 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=0.25,width=800,height=600,acodec=none}:http{mux=ogg,dst=:8181/graph.ogg}' --ttl=3
```

For testing purposes, I opened the stream on another machine using VLC, so I ruled out that it;s the video tag that's hanging. The player displays a frame near the beginning of the opened stream, but then doesn't update.

When opening the file in a firefox video element, 15 seconds of the stream are displayed, not more.

Are my streaming settings wrong?

More info: I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 to stream the window, and Windows 7 to play the stream.

Comment: With alternative source is the effect the same? (diferent video for example or audio file)

Comment: And is it the image that freezes or its a full freeze?
Tried diferent versions of VLC to figure if its not a version bug?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: [How to use VLC live streams with HTML5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917905/how-to-use-vlc-live-streams-with-html5-video)

Live/Real Time Streaming: VLC was used and in order to make it work I had to navigate around WebGL/HTML5 Video security restrictions.

It happens that video streams that do not originate from the same web server and web context or sub-context it will not be played due to security restrictions.

Comment: I'm reading the link you sent. Do you think opening the from-linux stream on the windows machine, that also serves the html5 page, and restreaming it work? That said, I don't think that's the issue, because the stream would stop after 15 seconds when opening it via VLC on the windows machine, as well.

Comment: I saw someone fix the "15 seconds" Firefox's issue by decreasing the framerate and resolution from the capture device. Another interresting fact: Firefox 3.0.15 uses totem plugin for HTML5 videos, but Firefox 3.5.5 does not. What version are you using?