# Video playback format natively supported by Firefox 13?

Tags: firefox-addon, video-streaming, video-codecs

Which video codec is natively supported in Firefox 13 for streaming? I have to create a Mozilla addon which should playback a video stream. I assume that flash is not available inside of a addon?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't support any streaming protocols natively. You can still send out video in WebM or Ogg Theora format over plain HTTP (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917905/how-to-use-vlc-live-streams-with-html5-video)) but it will be buffered and congestions will build up if the available bandwidth isn't sufficient. However, this might change soon as [WebRTC support is added to Firefox](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/04/webrtc-efforts-underway-at-mozilla/).